# Is .rda still available for new version of R

Tags: r

I tried to save a dataframe as .rda format. It works very well before. I cannot think of any reason beside I updated my R into 3.6.1

```
a=c(1,2,3)
b=c(4,5,6)
df<-data.frame(a,b)

save(df,file = 'test.Rda')
```

any idea what's going wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: when loading test.rda, it only gives me a string "df"

Comment: Please read [`?load`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/load), that's precisely what it is *supposed* to do: return a `character` vector of the variable names that were (in side-effect) loaded from the `.rda` file and placed in the calling environment.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the methodology of `saveRDS` and `readRDS`, that do *not* operate in side-effect: they store the contents of an object (and don't care about the name you choose).

Comment: One minor (to me, perhaps big to somebody) functional difference between using them is that `save` allows you to save multiple objects, while `saveRDS` only lets you save one. A way to compare them would be something like `save(aa, ab, ac, file="...")` is equivalent to `saveRDS(list(aa,bb,cc), file="...")`.

Comment: A quick read: https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/save-vs-saverds/

Comment: @r2evans Thank you so much!!! yes I understood the load() function wrongly!